# Find second latest date, billing number and stock

Tags: worksheet-function

If the quantity show zero or negative amount, I would need to find for the second latest date, billing number and quantity by using batch number.

[image: looking for second latest date, billing number and stock]

Sorry that I only know how to attach image instead of create link for excel data.

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(E2=0,LARGE(D12:D14,2),"")`

I think you'll be able to manage the others☺